# How to make several postgresql queries atomic (roll back in case of error)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL with nodejs for the first time. I want to make several PostgreSQL queries atomic in case of error.

For example:

```
    const group = Group.of(body);
    const { rows } = await this.db.query(
        `INSERT INTO groups
        (\"defaultImage\", \"createdAt\", \"updatedAt\")
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
        RETURNING *`,
        [group.defaultImage, group.createdAt, group.updatedAt]);

    const groupId = rows[0].id;

    group.images.map(image => {
        return this.db.query(
            `INSERT INTO groups_images
            (\"groups_id\", \"uri\")
            VALUES ($1, $2)`,
            [groupId, image.uri]);
    });
```

If the second query fails, I want the first to be rolled back

Comment: wrap your statements in `begin...commit`

Comment: Use a transaction.

Comment: but how can I get the id to use as FK in the second statement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Transaction will solve the problem as explained here:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()
;(async () => {
  // note: we don't try/catch this because if connecting throws an exception
  // we don't need to dispose of the client (it will be undefined)
  const client = await pool.connect()
  try {
    await client.query('BEGIN')
    const queryText = 'INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES($1) RETURNING id'
    const res = await client.query(queryText, ['brianc'])
    const insertPhotoText = 'INSERT INTO photos(user_id, photo_url) VALUES ($1, $2)'
    const insertPhotoValues = [res.rows[0].id, 's3.bucket.foo']
    await client.query(insertPhotoText, insertPhotoValues)
    await client.query('COMMIT')
  } catch (e) {
    await client.query('ROLLBACK')
    throw e
  } finally {
    client.release()
  }
})().catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
```

https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions